# Can I run multiple instances of the same spider via virtual environment

Tags: python, scrapy

I am developing a scraper. I finished it. Now I'm in the test phase to optimize several configurations to finish the job. Because there are 26000 lines of info and the catchy behaviour of the server, it takes some 12 hours the finish the scraping. As I make changes I feel the need to run one scraper, as I make a change, I want to run that separately, too, and possibly a third one and what not.

As far as I know because Scrapy uses Twisted it doesn't support multithreading. Is it possible to achieve what I intend above via venv?

ps: I use Google Computation Engine to do that for now.

Comment: why not just run them in separate processes?

Comment: Because I find out the necessary change after I run the scraper and analyze the logs. To run another process, I need the shut down the preexisting process. I don't want to close the former process.

Comment: Why do you need to shut down the existing process to run another one?

Comment: Because twisted doesn't allow that